# What class of Devil Fruit does the Gomu Gomu no Mi come under?

Tags: one-piece

Considering the three types of Devil Fruits that have been explained are:

1. Paramecia Type - where the user can get superhuman abilities and change their body parts into weapons, etc.
2. Zoan type - where the user can turn into a particular animal and inherit its abilities
3. Logia Type - where the user's body inherits a particular element and the body becomes like air which cannot be touched or damaged by non-Haki users.

So what exactly is the type of Gomu Gomu no Mi?

It cannot be Zoan or Logia. It's very close to a Paramecia but still doesn't have a logical explanation to be of Paramecia type. So is it some special type of Devil Fruit?

Comment: How do you know that it can't be a logia?  Maybe it's possible for logia to be based off of tangible elements too.

Comment: Gomu Gomu? The rubber one? That **changes body parts**? Also, wasn't it explicitly said several times that it was Paramecia?

Comment: Most of the answers on this post have been retconed and made obsolete/invalid. Now, the accepted answer is incorrect too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi).

> The Gomu Gomu no Mi is a ***Paramecia-type*** Devil Fruit that enables the user's body to stretch like rubber, making the user a Rubber Human.

You further ask..

> It's very close to a Paramecia but still doesn't have a logical explanation to be of Paramecia type!

Again from the [wiki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Paramecia).

> Paramecia is one of the three Devil Fruit types. ***These fruits give the users a power that can affect their body***, manipulate the environment, or produce substances. In general, Paramecia Devil Fruits are fruits that give their users powers other than transforming into elements, like Logias, or transforming into animals, like Zoans.

Answer (score 2):

I see the classifications as this:

- Logia: Turns your body into some sort of energy
- Zoan: Transforms you into an animal/legendary thing
- Paramecia: **THE REST**

So is it Logia? NO. Is it Zoan? NO. Then it is a Paramecia.

Comment: oh and the wiki says it is a paramecia as iKlsR pointed out so yeah

Answer (score 1):

Spoilers for a twist 1000+ chapters into the series

> First of all, it's not Gomu Gomu no Mi at all. It's actually the Hito Hito no Mi Model:Nika. The World Government has been trying to hide its existence for 800 years, thus they changed its name to Gomu Gomu no Mi, so everybody would think its related to rubber. From this point of view, it is a Paramecia type Devil Fruit.

> If we think about its original name, then it's a mythical Zoan type Devil Fruit.

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned on other websites then the wiki that it could be considered Logia. One of these examples is that Paramecia types can turn on and off, allowing changes of a person. The Gomu Gomu no Mi is a Devil Fruit which makes one like a rubber, permanently. You can not stop being rubber after congesting it. Meaning, it has traits of a Logia. It also comes along with the benefits that rubber has which is stretching, no blunt damage (without Haki), and no damage from electricity, and you could consider rubber an element.

Comment: Gomu Gomu no Mi is confirmed to be Paramecia by the author, discussions on any other forum (or wiki, for that matter) doesn't matter.

Comment: then we could say the same about buggy the clown , his ability is always active and can be sliced always then that means, he is logia too? NO still paramecia

Comment: It is the exact oposit. Logia can be turned on and off at will while Paramecia bring their own rules. E.g. Alvida can't turn off her Sube Sube no Mi either but Blackbeard can be fully human but (unlike every other Logia) not fully darkness.

Answer (score 0):

Luffy is a special Paramecia like Katakuri, or he is a special Logia like Black Beard.

Reasons: for special Paramecia, Luffy is permanently rubber, Katakuri is permanently mochi, they both have abilities uncannily similar to a Logia and a Paramecia. Also, I'm pretty sure it was stated that gomu is a weaker version of mochi. The only reason Luffy won is because Luffy is in his prime and Katakuri isn't, and Luffy was more creative. But if that wasn't stated, gomu might actually be the superior version because he hasn't awakened gomu and still beat Katakuri.

Reasons: for special Logia like Black Beard, because rubber is a natural element but Luffy can't go intangible with it like Black Beard can't with yami, and gomu's awakening might be giving him the intangibility of rubber tree sap.

But also, if it is like that, it could still be a special Paramecia because Katakuri is, but maybe before his awakening, he was like tangible stretchy dough, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

At this point everyone knows that luffy actually has a human human devil fruit like chopper. The mythical type is that of someone who had a rubber body; much like chopper will always revert to his default mix between reindeer and human; not his original reindeer form. Meaning that no matter how much sea prism stone luffy is subjected to he will always retained the rubber quality(this is counter to Logia types). As we have seen during the Nami arc when they stretched his head out of the water (seriously how strong are his lung to get oxygen from such a small straw?), but we see the mochi fruit revert once water is applied.

I kind of wonder that if Garp didn’t train him to an extreme level that he would have transformed much sooner; like Marcos with the phoenix. Maybe garp even knew about the fake name and tried to mislead him the whole time?

I digress don quixote had a paramecia type because he could make strings out of anything and could produce an exact clone with strings but in the end all his strings could do to his own body was to hold his organs together while he healed. Could he have left his consciousness in one of his string clones? Maybe but he wouldn’t have conqueror's if he would dilute his ruler’s linage (I wonder if he had more of a scientific mind he could have connected his strings to strings to the fabric of the universe: string theory. He could have controlled reality itself).

Katakuri’s mochi powers are logia because his whole body turns is into mochi and doesn’t experience damage unless sea prism or Haki is applied. This is the first time we get to see a logia cover their ability in Haki.

The idea that mochi doesn’t come from nature is so dumb. It’s 100 percent a natural substance just like tree gum. We wouldn’t have in-organic rubbers if these things where never found in nature.

Answer (score -1):

Luffy is a special paramecia that is half logia, half paramecia. The only reason that he is classified paramecia is due to one fact, rubber isn't a natural element.